# PHP + MySQL newsfeed approach?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, feed

I'm working on a newsfeed for my app like the one you have at Facebook. All newsfeed posts are in the same DB table called `newsfeed`. My app evolves mainly around users and events. The `newsfeed` table has a `newsfeed_type` column (int, 1-14 referring to id's in an `newsfeed_types` table). Each newsfeed entry also has an `other_id` and `other_tabl`e + `item_id` and `item_table`. For example a user posts something to an event; the *user* is the `other_id` belonging to `users` table and the *event* is the `item_id` belonging to the `events` table.

Ideally I want to garb around 20 posts sorted by descending timestamp and load the rest with "infinite scrolling" in my app. How PHP my script currently works is that it first collects every event the user is attending and all the users that user is following/friends with in *separate* arrays. Then it iterates the two arrays one after another with an SQL query:

#### Events

```
$query = "select * from newsfeed where (other_id = ". $event["id"] ." and other_table = 'events') or (item_id = ". $event["id"] ." and item_table = 'events') order by date desc limit 10";
```

#### Users

```
$query = "select * from newsfeed where newsfeed_type != 5 and ((other_id = ". $user["id"] ." and other_table = 'users') or (item_id = ". $user["id"] ." and item_table = 'users')) order by date desc limit 10";
```

I made the script without realising that it asks for 10 entries for each event and user. Making it ask for 1 entry wouldn't really be ideal either as the user can follow an infinite number of events and users with only one newsfeed post per item.

What do you reckon is the best practice to make it grab only the 20 most recent entries in the `newsfeed` table without having to iterate the two arrays in order to grab their data required for getting the newsfeed entries one at the time? I imagine I could collect the `id`'s and `table` in one string and make a SQL query grab everything in one go instead of inside a loop or something, but thought I'd ask you guys in case someone has dealed with that issue and came up with a genius solution.

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because `$_GET` data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.
**NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query.

Comment: @tadman Thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution. Instead of grabbing each user type and storing them in separate arrays to iterate through them, I foreach'ed both arrays separately and made a single string to be used as a sql query with a limit of 25 items.

```
$sql_string = "";

foreach ($events as $event) {

    $sql_snippet = "(other_id = ". $event["id"] ." and other_table = 'events') or (item_id = ". $event["id"] ." and item_table = 'events')";

    if ($is_adding == "true") {
        $last_id = $_POST["last_id"];
        $sql_snippet .= " and id < $last_id";
    }

    if ($sql_string == "") {
        $sql_string = "(". $sql_snippet .") ";
    } else {
        $sql_string .= "or (". $sql_snippet .") ";
    }
}

foreach ($users as $user) {

    $sql_snippet = "(other_id = ". $user["id"] ." and other_table = 'users') or (item_id = ". $user["id"] ." and item_table = 'users')";

    if ($is_adding == "true") {
        $last_id = $_POST["last_id"];
        $sql_snippet .= " and id < $last_id";
    }

    if ($sql_string == "") {
        $sql_string = "(". $sql_snippet .") ";
    } else {
        $sql_string .= "or (". $sql_snippet .") ";
    }
}

$query = "select * from newsfeed where newsfeed_type = 12 or ($sql_string) order by date desc limit 25";
```